# A good XCode sample project with SQlite, tableview, starring and reordering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm a complete newbie to Objective-C/XCode and it's been a bit daunting so far. I wanted to get my hands dirty by building something that incorporates a few concepts.

All I want to do is have a table which is populated by rows from a SQLite database. The table should have reordering capability, I want to have a starring facility, and then delete (which I believe is standard)

Of course I can stitch this by looking at a few sample projects, but I was wondering if there is a good sample project that has these features I could look at as a starting point. If there isn't, any other recommended sample projects that have parts of this are also thankfully received.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are new to the platform and your needs are straightforward, I would suggest usi Core Data.   The conceptual guide included with the documentation is quite good and there are tons of online resources, too.

There is very little reason to use Sqlite directly (and many many reasons not too).

Comment: The sample project iPhoneCoreDataRecipes has most of the features mentioned included

Comment: Thanks - I looked at it and it seems that is the best fit!

Comment: I can confirm now that using coredata was the right thing to do! thanks.